# Is there a reason why this function does not exist/can't be found?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, harmonic-numbers, discrete-calculus

I'm looking at a function $f\colon \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$, defined such that $(\Delta f)(x) = 1/x$. However, I know such a function does not exist or has not been found yet. I'm interested in why we can't find it. Is it because we lack the sufficient tools? Has it been proven not to exist?

Note: Edited again to restrict the domain

Comment: Wouldn't $\Delta f$ need to be integer-valued?

Comment: Yeah I missed that. Edited

Comment: What makes you think this function does not exist?

Comment: Wouldn't we have a closed formula for Harmonic numbers if it existed?

Comment: There is a definite integral which generalises the harmonic numbers for any number, not just integers, as J.G. indicates in an answer below. That definite integral is the the "closed form." Another form (probably) does not exist in terms of common elementary functions.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x):=\int_0^1\dfrac{1-t^{x-1}}{1-t}dt$ so $\Delta f(x):=f(x+1)-f(x)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1} dt=\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: As has been alluded, this is just $\psi (x)+\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\Delta f=f(n+1)-f(n)$, so you are looking for $$f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac{1}{n}.$$
So it looks like $$f(n)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}=H_{n-1}$$ should work.

**Proof**
$$f(n+1)-f(n)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{n}.$$